# installing bochs on mac 10.8.3

Tags: macos, bochs

I'm trying to install bochs emulator on mac machine which runs mac osx 10.8.3 But when I run the ./configure and make
I get the following error at the end of the make

```
carbon.cc:1318: error: ‘PaletteHandle’ was not declared in this scope
carbon.cc:1318: error: expected `;' before ‘thePal’
carbon.cc:1329: error: ‘RGBDirect’ was not declared in this scope
carbon.cc:1331: error: ‘GetPort’ was not declared in this scope
carbon.cc:1339: error: ‘SetEntries’ was not declared in this scope
carbon.cc:1341: error: ‘CTabChanged’ was not declared in this scope
carbon.cc:1343: error: ‘SetPort’ was not declared in this scope
carbon.cc:1350: error: ‘thePal’ was not declared in this scope
carbon.cc:1350: error: ‘pmTolerant’ was not declared in this scope
carbon.cc:1350: error: ‘NewPalette’ was not declared in this scope
carbon.cc:1351: error: ‘oldpal’ was not declared in this scope
carbon.cc:1351: error: ‘GetPalette’ was not declared in this scope
carbon.cc:1353: error: ‘SetPalette’ was not declared in this scope
carbon.cc:1359: error: ‘RGBDirect’ was not declared in this scope
carbon.cc: In member function ‘virtual void bx_carbon_gui_c::graphics_tile_update(Bit8u*, unsigned int, unsigned int)’:
carbon.cc:1397: error: ‘GetPort’ was not declared in this scope
carbon.cc:1400: error: ‘OffsetRect’ was not declared in this scope
carbon.cc:1403: error: ‘LockPortBits’ was not declared in this scope
carbon.cc:1405: error: ‘GetPixBaseAddr’ was not declared in this scope
carbon.cc:1409: error: ‘GetPixRowBytes’ was not declared in this scope
carbon.cc:1418: error: ‘GetPixRowBytes’ was not declared in this scope
carbon.cc:1420: error: ‘UnlockPortBits’ was not declared in this scope
carbon.cc:1422: error: ‘RGBForeColor’ was not declared in this scope
carbon.cc:1423: error: ‘RGBBackColor’ was not declared in this scope
carbon.cc:1424: error: ‘GetPortBitMapForCopyBits’ was not declared in this scope
carbon.cc:1425: error: ‘CopyBits’ was not declared in this scope
carbon.cc:1426: error: ‘QDError’ was not declared in this scope
carbon.cc:1428: error: ‘SetPort’ was not declared in this scope
carbon.cc: In member function ‘virtual void bx_carbon_gui_c::dimension_update(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int)’:
carbon.cc:1459: error: ‘DisposeGWorld’ was not declared in this scope
carbon.cc:1461: error: ‘GetCTable’ was not declared in this scope
carbon.cc: In member function ‘virtual unsigned int bx_carbon_gui_c::create_bitmap(const unsigned char*, unsigned int, unsigned int)’:
carbon.cc:1529: warning: ‘GetCIcon’ is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Headers/Icons.h:308)
carbon.cc:1529: warning: ‘GetCIcon’ is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Headers/Icons.h:308)
carbon.cc: In member function ‘virtual unsigned int bx_carbon_gui_c::headerbar_bitmap(unsigned int, unsigned int, void (*)())’:
carbon.cc:1582: error: ‘SetRect’ was not declared in this scope
carbon.cc: In member function ‘virtual void bx_carbon_gui_c::exit()’:
carbon.cc:1641: error: ‘InitCursor’ was not declared in this scope
carbon.cc:1644: warning: ‘CallInScrapPromises’ is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Headers/Scrap.h:649)
carbon.cc:1644: warning: ‘CallInScrapPromises’ is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Headers/Scrap.h:649)
carbon.cc: In function ‘void HidePointer()’:
carbon.cc:1678: error: ‘HideCursor’ was not declared in this scope
carbon.cc:1680: error: ‘SetPt’ was not declared in this scope
carbon.cc:1681: error: ‘LocalToGlobal’ was not declared in this scope
carbon.cc:1683: warning: ‘GetMouse’ is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Headers/Events.h:384)
carbon.cc:1683: warning: ‘GetMouse’ is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Headers/Events.h:384)
carbon.cc: In function ‘void ShowPointer()’:
carbon.cc:1694: error: ‘InitCursor’ was not declared in this scope
carbon.cc: In function ‘void UpdateTools()’:
carbon.cc:1708: warning: ‘GetCurrentScrap’ is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Headers/Scrap.h:263)
carbon.cc:1708: warning: ‘GetCurrentScrap’ is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Headers/Scrap.h:263)
carbon.cc:1712: warning: ‘GetScrapFlavorFlags’ is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Headers/Scrap.h:293)
carbon.cc:1712: warning: ‘GetScrapFlavorFlags’ is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Headers/Scrap.h:293)
carbon.cc: In function ‘void CreateKeyMap()’:
carbon.cc:1996: warning: ‘NewPtrClear’ is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/MacMemory.h:605)
carbon.cc:1996: warning: ‘NewPtrClear’ is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/MacMemory.h:605)
carbon.cc: In function ‘void CreateVGAFont(unsigned char*)’:
carbon.cc:2014: error: ‘SetRect’ was not declared in this scope
carbon.cc:2021: warning: ‘NewPtrClear’ is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/MacMemory.h:605)
carbon.cc:2021: warning: ‘NewPtrClear’ is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/MacMemory.h:605)
carbon.cc: In function ‘BitMap* CreateBitMap(unsigned int, unsigned int)’:
carbon.cc:2047: error: ‘SetRect’ was not declared in this scope
carbon.cc: In member function ‘virtual void bx_carbon_gui_c::beep_on(float)’:
carbon.cc:2103: warning: ‘AlertSoundPlay’ is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Headers/SystemSound.h:124)
carbon.cc:2103: warning: ‘AlertSoundPlay’ is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Headers/SystemSound.h:124)
make[1]: *** [carbon.o] Error 1
make: *** [gui/libgui.a] Error 2
```

so any clue how to install the bochs on my system?
Thanks